# why is 'headlines.add(xpp.nextText());' is giving me an error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, methods, boolean

I am new to programming with java.

just trying to work out why my piece of code isn't working.

```
boolean insideItem = false;
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
            insideItem = true;      
} else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
    if (insideItem)
        headlines.add(xpp.nextText());
} else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
    if (insideItem)
        links.add(xpp.nextText());**boolean insideItem = false;
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
            insideItem = true;      
} else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
    if (insideItem)
        headlines.add(xpp.nextText());
} else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
    if (insideItem)
        links.add(xpp.nextText());
```

it gives me the following error:

The method add(capture#3-of ?) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (String)

any idea how this can be solved?
and can someone explain to me why it doesn't work?

Edit:

heres the whole listActivity code:

```
public class Main_Menu extends ListActivity {

List<?> headlines;
List<?> links;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__menu);


headlines = new ArrayList();
links = new ArrayList();

try{
URL url = new URL ("http://feeds.ign.com/ign/all");

XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

boolean insideItem = false;
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
            insideItem = true;      
} else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
    if (insideItem)
        headlines.add(xpp.nextText());
} else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
    if (insideItem)
        links.add(xpp.nextText());
    }
}else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
    insideItem=false;
}

    eventType = xpp.next();

}   

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing the initialization of the Lists but I'm guessing you need to change:

```
List links = new ArrayList();
```

to:

```
List<String> = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: What is this: `**boolean insideItem = false;`???

Here is the documentation for XmlPullParser:

> *
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html
>
> If current event is START_TAG then if next element is TEXT then
>   element content is returned or if next event is END_TAG then empty
>   string is returned, otherwise exception is thrown.

I suspect you're just pulling up an element that doesn't happen to be a text element.

Look at the example code on the link, and consider restructuring your code accordingly.

IMHO...